# Does NDB still index with default=None or properties set to None?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'd like to be able to run a query like: `MyModel.query(MyModel.some_property == None)` and get results. I know that if I don't put a `default=<some default>` in a property, I won't be able to query for it, but if I set `default=None` will it index it?

Similarly, does setting values to `None` cause properties to be indexed in `ndb.Model`? What if you pass `some_keyword_arg=None` to the constructor?

I know that doing something like: `ndb.StringProperty(default='')` means you can query on it, just not clear on the semantics of using `None`.

Answer (score 6):

Explicitly setting a property to None is defining a value, and yes defaults work and the property will be indexed.  This assumes None is a valid value for a particular property type.

Some issues will arise, as you pointed out, often you use None as a sentinal value, so how do you tell between no Value provided and an explicit None?

Comment: The difference doesn't necessarily matter to me. It's more that I want to be able to find entities that didn't get the property set (e.g., not updated, etc) later on. So for a StringProperty, `''` might mean the property was explicitly cleared whereas `None` might mean that the property was never explicitly set.

Comment: Thats how I use it.  Unfortunately some properties in db like EmailProperty barf on explicitly setting it to None or '' as neither are valid email addresses.  This is why I completely dropped using these types of properties where the value is optional.  I haven't checked the behaviour of these properties in ndb.

Comment: Good suggestion - I agree that it's unfortunate though.