# What's the difference to set default value None or '' in Google cloud DataStore models?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a question about the `None` and `''` value when I use DataStore in Google Cloud.
e.g.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=None)
    name = ndb.StringProperty(default='')
    address = ndb.StringProperty(default=None)
```

I sets the default value because I wanna index and retrieve a list of entities that one of the properties doesn't been put value.
What's the difference to set StringProperty default value as `''` or `None`?
Which one is better and Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the indexing perspective there is no difference: both `None` and `''` are actual values that the property will then have (as opposed to the value not being set at all) and thus the entity will be indexed. See also: [Does NDB still index with default=None or properties set to None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767951/does-ndb-still-index-with-default-none-or-properties-set-to-none)

Setting a `StringProperty` to `None` (if even allowed) will require additional type checking when it is used, since it could contain both `string` and `None` type values. Setting its default value to `''` will not need such checks as `''` is a string - so the property will always contain `string` values.

Comment: Thanks, Dan! I have another problem. When I've put value to one property, I cannot change the value to None again. I can only put string '' to this property when I want to reset them, is it correct? This means '' is better?

Comment: That would be inline with setting a default value for it. For properties I want to unset I just delete them with `del entity.property` before saving them, but I'm unsure if that works with properties having a default value - kinds voids the whole purpose of having a default value.